# Mongodb: How to order a "select in" in same order as elements of the array

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm performing this mongo query:

```
db.mytable.find({id:{$in:["1","2", "3", "4" ]}});
```

It returns all results in a strange order, as it follows:

```
4,3,2,1
```

I need to retrieve all results in same order as it was defined in the query array.

```
1,2,3,4
```

Is it possible ?

Comment: This is programming, all things are possible that are just code related. They just may take time.

Comment: it's not possible to have mongoDB return the results in the specified order.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note:

1.) MongoDB, like most databases, makes no guarantees about the order of results returned from your query unless you use a call to `sort()`. If you really want to guarantee that your query result is returned in a a specific order, you'll need to specify that specific sort order.

2.) In general, the most recently updated/moved document will show up at the end of your result set but there are still no guarantees. MongoDB uses "natural order" for its native ordering of objects and although this is very close to the order of insertion, it is not guaranteed to be the same.

3.) Indexed fields will behave differently. It's worth pointing out that it looks like your query is using `id` and not `_id`. The former, `_id` would be indexed by default and `id` would not be indexed unless you've explicitly added an index to that field.

You can read more about MongoDB's sorting and ordering here:
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Sorting+and+Natural+Order

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed no guarantee about the order of results returned from your query, but you could do a sort afterwards with the result. Two examples, the first one with the order you wanted, the second one reversed.

```
const arr = ["1", "2", "3", "4" ];

db.collection.find({ id: { $in: arr }})  
  .then(result => {
    
    let sorted = arr.map(i => result.find(j => j.id === i));
    console.log(sorted) // 1, 2, 3, 4

    let reversed = arr.reverse().map(i => result.find(j => j.id === i));
    console.log(reversed) // 4, 3, 2, 1
    
});
```

In case you want to do real MongoDB ID lookups, use `db.collection.find({ _id: { $in: arr }})` and `.map(i => result.find(j => j._id == i))` (Notice the two equal signs instead of three)

Comment: Now how do you do it in an aggregate query itself?

Answer (score 1):

you can write a query like this :

```
db.mytable.find({id:{$in:["1","2", "3", "4" ]}}).sort({id:1})
```

To have your results `ORDER BY id ASC`

Source : [MongoDB Advanced Queries](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%7B%7Bsort%28%29%7D%7D)

But if you just want to order the results based on your $in array, try to sort your $in array in the reverse order, the result regarding to the first element of your $in array is likely to appear as the last element of the results

Comment: My array list has no a defined order, the values might be alphanumeric as well... then, I'm afraid It won't be possible :(

Comment: @larrytron If it does not have a defined order, just reverse it's order, you don't need to know how the order is, e.g. you can use [array_reverse](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php) in PHP

Comment: Sorry dude, I don't get your idea. Imagine this other example: `db.mytable.find({id:{$in:["foo","bar", "baz", "qux" ]}});` then I need to retrieve exactly these values and same order as here (foo,bar,baz,qux) but I'm getting something like `qux,bar,foo,baz`.. I mean, totally different. hope it helps to clearify. thanks

Comment: OK, for that, there is no way I think.

Comment: There's no way to do what OP wants, without processing the array twice. You can use JS to sort in the order passed in, just like you could write that in any other language. It's just not reasonable to do so as a native extension to the library.

Comment: can anyone recommend me a fast sort algorithm ? also in nodejs?